# How to run Bash script with PHP and a Password

Tags: php, bash

How can I protect a bash script (Ubuntu) with a password and the call it with PHP?

If I simply use `ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:/var/www/my_bash_script.sh` this will allow to PHP to call the script from anywhere anytime without password, that's not what I want.

Comment: Put the password logic in the bash script itself as an argument, and call it like `/var/www/my_bash_script.sh <password>`.

Comment: A bash script is normally called with bash and a PHP script with PHP. What you certainly mean is to call a bash script from within a PHP script, correct? If so, please add a short example how you do it. Also please give some more details how the PHP script is executed (e.g. in which SAPI: Apache? Nginx? PHP-FPM? CLI?, ...). And how much are you concerned about `sudo(1)`, I've problems to interprete the short notice about it, you write you don't want that and it's not clear what the context of that is.

Answer (score 0):

PHP has a [number of options](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.exec.php) to do this.

With the very little information given, this sample is just a guess using the [`shell_exec`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php) option.

```
<?php
header('content-type: text/plain');
echo shell_exec('/var/www/my_bash_script.sh yourPassWord');
```

The file permissions of the `my_bash_script.sh` file are important.

They need to be suitable for execution by the same `user` or `group` that the webserver (effectively the php process that executes the php script and therefore the bash script) uses.